# Segmenting a series of Timedeltas to a minute by minute graph (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, dataframe

I have a dataframe with the index as a Timedelta, ranging from 0 to 5 minutes, and a column of floating point numbers.

Here's an example subset:

```
32  0.740283
34  0.572126
36  0.524788
38  0.509685
40  0.490219
42  0.545977
44  0.444170
46  1.098387
48  2.209113
51  1.426835
53  1.536439
55  1.196625
56  1.923569
```

The left being the timedelta in seconds, the right being the floating point number.

**The issue is when plotting with pandas I get an x axis with labels such as:

0 days 00:00:00, 0 days 00:01:10, 0 days 00:02:15**

and so on. Is there any way I can maybe resample (wrong word?) the data so that I can have axes on a minute by minute basis while still maintaining the data points in the right place?

Example code/data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'td':[32,34,36,38,40,42,44,51,53,152,283],
                   'val': np.random.rand(11)})

df.index = df.td.map(lambda x: pd.Timedelta(seconds=x.astype(int)))
df.drop(['td'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.val.plot()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas only provides plotting functions for convenience. To have full control, you need to use Matplotlib directly.

As a workaround, you could just use datetime instead of timedelta as index. As long as your timespans are within minutes, Pandas won't plot the day or month.

To use your example, this works:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'td':[32,34,36,38,40,42,44,51,53,152,283],
                   'val': np.random.rand(11)})
df.index = [dt(2010, 1, 1) + timedelta(seconds=int(i)) for i in df.td]
df.drop(['td'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.val.plot()
```

[image: time series plot]

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
td = np.array([32,34,36,38,40,42,44,51,53,152,283])*1e9  # if you don't multiply by 1e9, then pandas will assume you are referring to nanoseconds when you use the function pd.to_datetime()
df = pd.DataFrame({'td':td,
                   'val': np.random.rand(11)})

df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.td)
df.index = df.index.time  # select the time component of the index ... ignoring the date
df.drop('td', 1, inplace=True)

print df
              val
00:00:32  0.825991
00:00:34  0.578752
00:00:36  0.348558
00:00:38  0.221674
00:00:40  0.706031
00:00:42  0.912452
00:00:44  0.448185
00:00:51  0.368867
00:00:53  0.188401
00:02:32  0.855828
00:04:43  0.494732

df.plot()  # it gets the plot you want
```